# Xampp-Mysql-Eclipse connection error

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have installed eclipse and xampp in my mac and tried to connect with mysql server from eclipse using mysql-5.7.9-osx10.10-x86_64 connector.

I have the user "root@localhost" granted with all privileges to all databases.

1) I'm able to connect only mysql database in phpmyadmin server.

Unable to connect any other database. Am getting an error :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   database 'test'

2)After connecting with mysql database using

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","1234");
```

I created a table adminlogins in mysql database, and used command

```
"select * from mysql.adminlogins"
```

but I am getting an error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'mysql.adminlogins' doesn't exist.

I have tried all possible ways creating new user and granting all permissions. I am unable to figure out where am going wrong please some help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` database is reserved for system use. It is not recommended to create your own tables there. That said, the cause of your error is that the table was not created where you think it was if it was created at all.

Regardless, try creating the table in another database. If it does not work, post the exact commands that you used to create it with the messages that were returned.

Comment: thanks for your response. But when i tried to connect to other database from eclipse through jdbc connection am getting unknow database. i tried using following commands : Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/3306/coursedb","scott","1234");